# Problem with iCloud setting, pop-up warnings won't go away

Tags: icloud, apple-id, password

Since last week, I have been having this pop-up. I entered my password numerous times but it won't go away.

[image: AppleID panel]

I have also been getting the following warning. I open the AppleID panel and again enter my password. It seems to get accepted but then the pop-up comes up again.

[image: popup]

Answer (score 1):

We used to get this a lot because of one of our security products. Best bet: sign out of your iCloud completely, reboot your machine, and then sign back in.